# Extracting Classification Module From the CapsNet

Tags: python, keras

With Reference to the concept of [Capsule Network](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6975-dynamic-routing-between-capsules.pdf), I am trying to extract just the classification module from the [Intel's Implementation of Capsules in Keras](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/understanding-capsule-network-architecture), As I don't need the decoder or reconstruction part that is provided in the mentioned link.

**My Try:**

So I just commented out the decoder part of the network

```
#dec = Dense(512, activation='relu')(mask)
#dec = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(dec)
#dec = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(dec)
#dec = Reshape(input_shape)(dec)
```

and the decoder argument in the following line

```
#model = Model([x, mask_input], [output_capsule, dec])
model = Model([x, mask_input], [output_capsule])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=[ margin_loss, 'mae' ], metrics=[ margin_loss, 'mae', 'accuracy'])
model.fit([X, Y], [Y, X], batch_size=128, epochs=3, validation_split=0.2)
```

**Error**

I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: When passing a list as loss, it should have one entry per model outputs. The model has 1 outputs, but you passed loss=[<function margin_loss at 0x0000020C3E7A30D0>, 'mae']
```

**Help Required:**

Can somebody guide me how can I use that only the classification part of the Module because I have images that have dimension 90 x 90 and I want to use the classification part to check the accuracy and later on I would analyze each capsules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer why you are getting that error:

The original model has a two outputs. Each output has its own loss function. In this case, the outputs are `[output_capsule, dec]` and the corresponding loss functions are `[margin_loss, 'mae']`. Because you removed the `dec` output, you need to remove its loss function from the compilation of the model.

In addition, you will need to make sure that you are passing the correct inputs and outputs everywhere else. In the code that you have here, that matters for `model.fit`. The first argument is the inputs. You still have two inputs to your model (not sure if you *want* two inputs, but that's a different problem), so passing in a list of two inputs to `fit` is good. However, the second argument is the desired outputs. You're currently passing in two output arrays, but you only have one output for your model. Since you removed your model's second output, you should remove the second output that you pass in to `fit`, i.e. `X`.

Modified code:

```
model = Model([x, mask_input], [output_capsule])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=[margin_loss], metrics=[margin_loss, 'mae', 'accuracy'])
model.fit([X, Y], [Y], batch_size=128, epochs=3, validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was really helpful. Now I want to use my data as x_train,y_train and validation as x_test, y_test instead of X and Y that are used in the model. So I wrote the following line of code.  model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test),batch_size=128, epochs=3)               But it gave me following error  "ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[0.],
", whats wrong now?

Comment: @NaseerAhmed Same thing, but for inputs.

Comment: I tried "model = Model(x, [output_capsule])" and then it worked but the mask was an essential part of the algorithm, I mean mask was an essential element of the algorithm , how it worked without that, I am really surprised.